# Finding unusual phrases using a "bag of usual phrases"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, text-mining

My goal is to input an array of phrases as in

```
array = ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.","At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.","Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."]
```

and to present a new phrase to it, like

```
"Felix qui potuit rerum cognoscere causas"
```

and I want it to tell me whether this is likely part of the group in the aforementioned `array` or not.

I found how to detect frequencies of words, but how do I find `unsimilarity`? After all, my goal is to find unusual phrases, not the frequency of certain words.

Comment: For phrases in english (i'm not sure about other languages) you can use `wordnet` from `nltk.corpus`... What language are you asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a simple "language model" for this purpose. It will estimate probability of a phrase, and mark phrases with low average per-word probability as unusual.

For word probability estimation, it can use a smoothed word count.

This is how the model could look like:

```
import re
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

class LanguageModel:
    """ A simple model to measure 'unusualness' of sentences. 
    delta is a smoothing parameter. 
    The larger delta is, the higher is the penalty for unseen words.
    """
    def __init__(self, delta=0.01):
        self.delta = delta
    def preprocess(self, sentence):
        words = sentence.lower().split()
        return [re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z]+", '', word) for word in words]
    def fit(self, corpus):
        """ Estimate counts from an array of texts """
        self.counter_ = Counter(word 
                                 for sentence in corpus 
                                 for word in self.preprocess(sentence))
        self.total_count_ = sum(self.counter_.values())
        self.vocabulary_size_ = len(self.counter_.values())
    def perplexity(self, sentence):
        """ Calculate negative mean log probability of a word in a sentence 
        The higher this number, the more unusual the sentence is.
        """
        words = self.preprocess(sentence)
        mean_log_proba = 0.0
        for word in words:
            # use a smoothed version of "probability" to work with unseen words
            word_count = self.counter_.get(word, 0) + self.delta
            total_count = self.total_count_ + self.vocabulary_size_ * self.delta
            word_probability = word_count / total_count
            mean_log_proba += np.log(word_probability) / len(words)
        return -mean_log_proba

    def relative_perplexity(self, sentence):
        """ Perplexity, normalized between 0 (the most usual sentence) and 1 (the most unusual)"""
        return (self.perplexity(sentence) - self.min_perplexity) / (self.max_perplexity - self.min_perplexity)

    @property
    def max_perplexity(self):
        """ Perplexity of an unseen word """
        return -np.log(self.delta / (self.total_count_ + self.vocabulary_size_ * self.delta))

    @property
    def min_perplexity(self):
        """ Perplexity of the most likely word """
        return self.perplexity(self.counter_.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

You can train this model and apply it to different sentences.

```
train = ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
                 "At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.",
                 "Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."]
test = ["Felix qui potuit rerum cognoscere causas", # an "unlikely" phrase
        'sed diam nonumy eirmod sanctus sit amet', # a "likely" phrase
       ]

lm = LanguageModel()
lm.fit(train)

for sent in test:
    print(lm.perplexity(sent).round(3), sent)
```

which prints to you

```
8.525 Felix qui potuit rerum cognoscere causas
3.517 sed diam nonumy eirmod sanctus sit amet
```

You can see that "unusualness" is higher for the first phrase than for the second, because the second one is made from the training words.

If your corpus of "usual" phrases is large enough, you can switch from 1-gram models I use to N-grams (for English, sensible N is 2 or 3). Alternatively, you can use recurrent neural nets to predict probability of each word conditional on all the previous words. But this requires a really huge training corpus.

If you work with a highly flective language, like Turkish, you can use character-level N-grams instead of a word-level model, or just preprocess your texts using a lemmatization algorithm from NLTK.

Comment: It seems that random literals always cause 12.124, so this seems to be the most unusual phrase, while roughly 4 seems to be the highest similarity. So a switch at 8.062 might be useful for determining usualness and unusualness, what is your take?

Comment: Yes, something like this. This lower and upper bounds on unusualness (4 and 12.124) depend on the training corpus and on the delta, so you should adjust the threshold to the actual data you are going to use.

Comment: So I put a `dissimilar = lm.perplexity("jkdhfl dgksh dfkslgh dskflg dskjfgkljs dn").round(3)` and a `similar = lm.perplexity(train[0]).round(3)`, then a `dissimilarity_in_per_cent = ((100/(dissimilar - similar))*lm.perplexity(sent).round(3))-((100/(dissimilar - similar))*similar)` in the code. Unfortunately, I sometimes get  minus percentage for testing with other sentences of my training array. Without iterating through every `train` how do I get the lowest number for similarity?

Comment: @VitalisHommel, I have extended my class to calculate relative "dissimilarity" of any sentence.

Answer (score 0):

For finding common phrases in sentence you can use [Gensim Phrase (collocation) detection](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html)

But if you want to detect unusual phrases maybe you will ***describe some part of speech combination patterns with RegEx*** and ***doing POS tagging on input sentence*** you will be able to **extract** unseen words(phrases) which match with your pattern.